# how to trim() String in List<String> using JAVA 8 Lambda expression

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8

I am looking for all type of string manipulation using java 8 Lambda expressions.

I first tried the `trim()` method in simple `String` list.

```
String s[] = {" S1","S2 EE ","EE S1 "};
List<String> ls = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(s);
ls.stream().map(String :: trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(ls.toString());
```

For this example, I was expecting to get `[S1, S2 EE, EE S1]`,
but I got `[ S1, S2 EE , EE S1 ]`.

Comment: The type cast `(List<String>)` should not be necessary.

Comment: @Holger If I did not cast Eclipse shows a warning.

Comment: @Tunaki I searched all over inside Stackoverflow.com, but did not find one. If a question does exist so, please let know the URL for that post.

Comment: You have the link at the top of your question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`collect()` produces a new `List`, so you must assign that `List` to your variable in order for it to contain the trimmed `String`s :

```
ls = ls.stream().map(String :: trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or just do the whole op in-place: `ls.replaceAll(String::trim);`

Comment: So now I have 2 solutions and both are working perfect. Now which one of these do I need to use as a best practice.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk Well, Holger's suggestion is more elegant and saves the creation of a new List instance, so I'd use it.

Comment: @Eran Thanks! And where can I refer for all string manipulation on a list using lambda.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk I don't understand your question. If you have a specific question you can't find the answer to, you can always post a new question here.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk I would suggest you to read the Oracle Stream tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/. They are quite comprehensive and cover a lot of aspects.